# Can I create a local API?

Tags: reactjs, api

I'm learning about fetch and promises on reactjs, and sometimes I had a problem with my internet connection. So is it possible for me to create my own API but still can use or call it with `fetch()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use mocking tools to mock the APIs.
One such example is https://mockoon.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a local server and use `fetch()` to pull from `localhost`.

This is an example Node server:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.send('test')
})

const server = app.listen(8081, () => {
  console.log("Example app up")
})
```

You can then `fetch()` from `localhost:8081`

Answer (score 0):

> We can locally read the JSON data using fetch API in JavaScript. If you are using react hooks, place it inside the `useEffect` hook.

Check the console in this code sample [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-pare-nec3s?file=/src/index.js)

> Code: Your `data.json` will contain the sample JSON data.

```
fetch("./data.json")
  .then(function (response) {
    return response;
  })
  .then(function (data) {
    return data.json();
  })
  .then(function (finalData) {
    console.log(finalData);
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log("Fetch problem show: " + err.message);
  });
```